# mod_rewrite deny access if parameter equals something

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have urls like
mydomain.com?act=somethingbad
mydomain.com?act=somethingworse
and
mydomain.com?act=somethinggood
mydomain.com?act=somethingbetter

I need to make bad actions forbidden.
Tried something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} act=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} act=[^(somethinggood)]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [F]
```

Because I have more bad actions than good I want to exclude de good actions from this rule.
But the above example doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)act=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)act=(somethinggood|somethingbetter)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [F]
```

1. Parameter `act` can be any where (e.g. `http://example.com/?act=somethinggood` and `http://example.com/?mode=happy&act=somethinggood` and `http://example.com/?mode=happy&act=somethinggood&extra=yes` will be OK)
2. If you will have empty value for `act` parameter, it will be rejected (e.g. `http://example.com/?act=` is treated as BAD parameter)
3. Based on URL examples you have provided, this rule will be applied for ALL URLs that have `act` parameter in query string.