# How can I use .htaccess to block access when a parameter is empty?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs like this: page.php?param1=xxx&param2=yyy

Using .htaccess, I want to block access when param2 is not specified or is empty. I don't mind about param1. So the following should be blocked:

- page.php?param2=
- page.php?param1=somevalue
- page.php

But these should be allowed:

- page.php?param2=somevalue
- page.php?param1=somevalue&param2=anothervalue

I'm aware of [mod_rewrite deny acces if parameter equals something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610468/mod-rewrite-deny-acces-if-parameter-equals-something), but my RegEx isn't good enough to modify that answer for my purposes.

My server is running Apache 2.4 on CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)param2=[^&]+(&|$)
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ - [NC,F]
```